# Searching, sorting and printing a sorted 2D array of integers in C

Tags: c, sorting, search, multidimensional-array, max

I am having trouble in printing the location of the maximum in a 2d array of integers. i.e. the element array[33][2] with value 500 is maximum, where [33] signifies the 33rd week and [2] signifies the 2nd day. I want to printf (" The maximum is 500 and is found on day : X") as well as printf (" The greatest week is : Y") (for the week one it is the greatest sum of the seven consecutive days within the week that is achieved)

Also, when I try to sort the 2D array of integers, the print of the sorted version is not sorted...
I'm using bubble sort with temp:

```
for (i=0; i<100;i++){
for(j=0;j<7;j++){
fscanf(filetoreadfrom,"%d\n",&array[i][j]);

    if(array[i][j] < array[i][j+1]){

    temp=array[i][j];
    array[i][j]=array[i][j+1];
    array[i][j+1]=temp;
    }}}
```

I am lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting the data before reading all of it.  First read the data:

```
for (i=0; i<100;i++){
  for(j=0;j<7;j++){
    fscanf(filetoreadfrom,"%d\n",&array[i][j]);
  }
 }
```

Then do the sorting:

```
for (i=0; i<100;i++){
  for(j=0;j<7;j++){
    if(array[i][j] < array[i][j+1]){
      temp=array[i][j];
      array[i][j]=array[i][j+1];
      array[i][j+1]=temp;
    }
  }
}
```

And your sort algorithm is not correct. For example, when `j` is 6, the statement `array[i][j]=array[i][j+1];` tries to read `array[i][7]`.

Comment: if I placed j=0 at the end of the nested for would that solve the [7] problem?

Comment: no, you either need to switch to the next day, or just loop until j==5 depending on what you want to do. For the first case, create a function called get_next_day and return both i and j values from the function.

Comment: I tried creating the get_next_day function with no avail, how do you structure it properly?

Comment: How about an if-clause?
if (most days)

Comment: How about an if-clause? If (last day of week) next_j = 0; next_i += 1;. Try doing it in your head before trying to program the computer. Once you know exactly how to do it you can begin instructing the computer. The C compiler will never figure out things like this on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few random thoughts:
Indexing always begins with 0. 
There's no need to sort to find the largest number. 
Have you considered the possibility that to days or weeks might have the same value?
If you sort an array how do you expect to know where the data was to begin with?

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, the sorting and the searching are done in separate instances. The searching is for the maximum value and then print the day which contains that value, also print the week with the greatest summation of values. The sorting is done later for sorting the data in descending/ascending value.

Comment: If you find sorting a 2D array (matrix) hard maybe you should consider flattening it to an ordinary array before sorting?

Answer (score 0):

In bubble sort, you have to keep looping over the entire array until you don't have to swap any elements on a particular loop.  You only loop once, which won't work unless the array is almost sorted to begin with.

Also, you don't read in element `[i][j+1]` until after the loop for `[i][j]` is finished, so you're comparing `[i][j]` to whatever garbage is stored in `[i][j+1]`.  Read in all your elements before sorting them!

Comment: should I use a do while loop instead?

Comment: You may want to enclose the entire thing in a `do {} while (something was swapped on this iteration);` loop.

Comment: You may want to find some existing C code for bubble sort just to compare, since all bubble sorts are fundamentally the same.

Comment: By the way, do you actually need to sort, or just find the max?

Comment: sort is used separately from search, they are not used together in the application